# How to change the structure of eager loaded data efficiently in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm loading a product eagerly with its relationship data in Laravel.

```
$product = Product::with('attributeValues.attribute')->find($id)->get();
```

Currently I get the response structure as follows.

```
[
    {
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_name": "Shirt A",
        "attribute_values": [
            {
                "attribute_value_id": 1,
                "attribute_value": "small",
                "attribute": {
                    "attribute_id": 1,
                    "attribute": "size"
                }
            },
            {
                "attribute_value_id": 1,
                "attribute_value": "medium",
                "attribute": {
                    "attribute_id": 1,
                    "attribute": "size"
                }
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

The structure I expected to get is as follows.

```
[
    {
        "product_id": 1,
        "product_name": "Shirt A",
        "attribute": [
            {
                "attribute_id": 1,
                "attribute": "size",
                "attribute_values": [
                    {
                        "attribute_value_id": 1,
                        "attribute_value": "small"
                    },
                    {
                        "attribute_value_id": 1,
                        "attribute_value": "medium"
                    }
                ]
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

The current relationships of the models are as follows

```
class Product extends Model {
    public function attributeValues(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(AttributeValue::class, 'product_attributes');
    }
}

class AttributeValue extends Model {
    public function attribute(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class);
    }
}

class Attribute extends Model { }
```

Currently I'm succeeded getting this structure correctly by using product and getting it attributes separately using raw queries. I'm trying to achieve a Eloquent way of doing this task.

The tables I have are as follows

**products**

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
```

**product_attributes**

```
+----+------------+--------------------+
| id | product_id | attribute_value_id |
+----+------------+--------------------+
```

**attribute_values**

```
+----+--------------+-------+
| id | attribute_id | value |
+----+--------------+-------+
```

**attributes**

```
+----+-----------+
| id | attribute |
+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 3):

What about using [collections methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods) ? I'm not an expert but i would have done something like this :

```
$products->map(function($product){

  $attribute = $product->attribute_values->groupBy('attribute.attribute')->map(function($groupAttribute,$key){
    $attribute_values = $groupAttribute->map(function($attribute) {
        return ['attribute_value_id'=>$attribute->attribute_value_id,'attribute_value'=>$attribute->attribute_value];
    });
    return ['attribute_id' => 1 ,'attribute'=> $key , 'attribute_values' => $attribute_values  ];
  });

  return [
          'product_id'=>$product->product_id,
          'product_name'=>$product->product_name,
          'attribute'=>$attribute
        ];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `with` inside `with` using [custom eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading):

```
  $product = Product::with(['attributeValues'=>function($query){
            $query->select(['attribute_value_id','attribute_value'])
                ->with('attribute:attribute_id,attribute');
        }])->find($id)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following you will get the required result.

```
$product = Product::with('attribute.attributeValues')->find($id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `JsonResource`.

[Here you can find a short and easy example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-laravel-eloquent-api-resources-to-convert-models-into-json)

Just define ProductResource, attribyteValueResource, and AttributeResource

Here is the example:

**PropertyResource:**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class PropertyResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return [
            'product_id' => $this->product_id,
            'product_name' => $this->product_name,
            'attribute_values' => AttributeResource::collect( $this->whenLoaded('attributeValues') ),
        ];
    }
}
```

**AttributeValueResource:**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class AttributeValueResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return [
            'attribute_value_id' => $this->attribute_value_id,
            'attribute_value' => $this->attribute_value,
            'attribute' => AttributeValueResource::make( $this->whenLoaded('attribute') ),
        ];
    }
}
```

**AttributeResource:**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class AttributeResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request): array
    {
        return [
            'attribute_id' => $this->attribute_id,
            'attribute' => $this->attribute,
        ];
    }
}
```

Then just use them:

```
$product = ProductResource::make(
    Product::load('attributeValues.attribute')->find($id)
);
```

Comment: how is the performance of this approach? I mean there are a lot of queries running in the background by using resouces

Comment: It works without N+1 issue, because of `$this->whenLoaded()` method is using